# SAS export password protected Stata file

Tags: passwords, export, sas

I am trying to use SAS 9.3 to export a dataset into a .dta file, and have the Stata file be password-protected. Is this possible? I've seen a number of examples for exporting to Excel, but these all rely on creating an Excel file and then opening it to add the password. I don't have Stata, so can't open the .dta file I create to edit it.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm unaware of the ability to export to a password protected STATA file.

Comment: Unless there's some new capability I'm unaware of, I don't think you can't password-protect a .dta file even if you have Stata.